# relating Compress[] to information theory

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a question regarding the Compress[] function.  From my reading, Compress[] is based on zlib and should provide lossless compression.  Given a string (call it test), I would expect that, from information theory, ByteCount[Compress[test]]=ByteCount[Compress[test,test]].  I have tested this equality for many strings of different lengths, and it often (though does not always) hold.  I am wondering why this equality does not hold for some strings.  Does this have anything to do with string length, a wrapper, etc., or am I missing something obvious?  Thank you.  JR

Comment: `Compress[test,test]` is invalid syntax. Did you mean `Compress[test<>test]`?

Comment: I think there is more going on than you are accounting for.  Consider the following: `ByteCount[Compress["test"]]`: 56 
`ByteCount[Compress["test test"]]`: 64 
`ByteCount[Compress["test test test"]]`: 64 
`ByteCount["test"]`: 32
`ByteCount["test test"]`: 40
`ByteCount["test test test"]`: 40

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Did you have in mind `Compress[Compress[test]]`?